# Change name of data type in C

Tags: c

Is it possible to change the name of the data type that you will be using in your code? Say, instead of defining "int a", you want to do "my_type a" after telling the compiler that "my_type" = "int". Thanks.

Comment: `typedef`s can be easily misused, avoid it if you can. Read about this and more in the `Linux Kernel coding style` Chapter 5, https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, C supports this using a [`typedef` declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/typedef):

```
typedef int my_type;

my_type a;
```